# Reduce value of maximum value in multiple columns by one in pandas dataframe by group

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies - this is very similar to a query I had earlier but I was unable to delete as I'd made a mistake within it.

I simply want to find the maximum value **by group** in some of the columns (not all of them) in a dataframe - and reduce this grouped maximum value by one. It will be a single row, not multiple rows that have the maximum value.

So let's say I have a table with the following columns below. I want to reduce the maximum value by group (i.e. Name) in columns A, B and D by one:

```
Name A B C D
Bob  3 2 5 5
Bob  4 9 7 7 
Bob  6 0 1 3 
Jim  7 0 7 9 
Jim  1 3 9 1
Jim  2 7 1 5
```

The end result I'm looking for is where the maximum value by column (for columns A, B and D) by group is reduced by one, per below - but column C remains untouched. Thanks.

```
Name A B C D
Bob  3 2 5 5
Bob  4 8 7 6 
Bob  5 0 1 3 
Jim  6 0 7 8 
Jim  1 3 9 1
Jim  2 6 1 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) with the output of [`groupby.transform('max')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'D']

df.update(df[cols].clip(upper=df[cols].groupby(df['Name']).transform('max')-1))
```

Or, with a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
MAX = df[cols].groupby(df['Name']).transform('max')

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].eq(MAX), df[cols]-1)
```

Output:

```
  Name  A  B  C  D
0  Bob  3  2  5  5
1  Bob  4  8  7  6
2  Bob  5  0  1  3
3  Jim  6  0  7  8
4  Jim  1  3  9  1
5  Jim  2  6  1  5
```

Comment: Thank you - the clip solution is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim'],
                   'A': [3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 2],
                   'B': [2, 9, 0, 0, 3, 7],
                   'C': [5, 7, 1, 7, 9, 1],
                   'D': [5, 7, 3, 9, 1, 5]})

"""print(df)
  Name  A  B  C  D
0  Bob  3  2  5  5
1  Bob  4  9  7  7
2  Bob  6  0  1  3
3  Jim  7  0  7  9
4  Jim  1  3  9  1
5  Jim  2  7  1  5
"""

cols = ['A', 'B', 'D']

# Calculate maximum values by group for specified columns
max_values = df[cols].groupby(df['Name']).transform('max')
"""print(max_values)
   A  B  D
0  6  9  7
1  6  9  7
2  6  9  7
3  7  7  9
4  7  7  9
5  7  7  9"""
# Create a mask to identify elements equal to the maximum value
mask = df[cols].eq(max_values, axis=0)
"""print(mask)
       A      B      D
0  False  False  False
1  False   True   True
2   True  False  False
3   True  False   True
4  False  False  False
5  False   True  False"""
# Reduce elements in the mask by one while keeping column C untouched
df.update(df[cols].where(~mask, df[cols] - 1))
print(df)
""" Name  A  B  C  D
0  Bob  3  2  5  5
1  Bob  4  8  7  6
2  Bob  5  0  1  3
3  Jim  6  0  7  8
4  Jim  1  3  9  1
5  Jim  2  6  1  5
"""
```

Or

```
max_vals = df[cols].max(axis = 0) -1 
print(max_vals)
mask = df[cols].eq(max_vals,axis=0)
df.update(df[cols].where(~mask) )
print(df)
```

If You need a for loop. Sometimes essential.

```
for col in cols:
    max_values = df[col].groupby(df['Name']).transform('max')
    mask = df[col].eq(max_values)
    df.loc[mask, col] -= 1
```